# Can't store incoming message in my database using twilio

Tags: codeigniter, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using twilio for sending sms.i can sent sms but i can't receive incoming sms and can't store in my database.When i receive SMS from my customers to my twilio number. i want to get the fields like from number and the body and save to my databse.
In the below i gave codes.please tell whats the problem and what need to change to store data in my database.

View Code:

```
<!--sidebar end-->
<!--main content start-->
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
        <!-- page start-->
        <section class="panel panel--colour-orange">
            <header class="panel-heading">
            </header>

            <form role="form" action="patient/receivesmsadd" method="post" style="border: 0px solid #ccc; padding: 0px;">

            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 30px 20px 15px 15px;">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel-body-wrapper">
                        <li class="list-group-item" style="border-top: 2px solid #2789D9;">

                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Appointment id" name="appointment_id" id="appointment_id" class="numeric form-control" maxlength="13" value="<?php echo($_REQUEST['body[0]']); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Bill Process" name="acceptance" id="acceptance" class="numeric form-control" value="<?php echo($_REQUEST['body[1]']); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="payment_method" placeholder="Payment Method" id="payment_method" class="numeric form-control" value="<?php echo($_REQUEST['body[2]']); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="numeric form-control" value="<?php echo($_REQUEST['from']); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <section class="" style="margin-left: 25px;">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-blue" style="margin-left: 5px;margin-bottom: 30px;">Create</button>
        </section>
        </form>

        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

Controller Code:

```
function receivesmsadd(){
        $data = array();
        $data['appointment_id']        = $this->input->post('appointment_id');
        $data['acceptance']            = $this->input->post('acceptance');
        $data['payment_method']        = $this->input->post('payment_method');
        $data['phone']                 = $this->input->post('phone');

        $this->load->model('patient_model');
        if ($this->patient_model->receivesms($data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Added Successfully');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Failed to Added');
        }     
    }
```

Mode code:

```
 function receivesms($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('receivesms',$data);
    }
```

Comment: Inorder to receive SMS and store into your database, you need to configure webhook in twilio. Have you configured your webhook? If not please refer to twilio documentation for the same

Comment: yes i configure webhook

Comment: Are you getting all required variables in  $_POST? var_dump($this->input->post());

Comment: No thats why i share here

Comment: Where is the code that runs when the webhook is called by Twilio?